# Update a property value in my Documentdb

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following result in my document.
I wanted to update the property value for "Type" and "Workout", such that it doesn't effect other values

```
"PartyId": 10114795,
"WorkoutId": 4,
"Type": "heart-rate-zone-target",
"DateStarted": "2016-02-05T18:14:15.1620890Z",
"id": "0c44d1ee-58b8-4083-a702-f770ba0e63e9",
"_rid": "0ThoANQ4YwEEAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/0ThoAA==/colls/0ThoANQ4YwE=/docs/0ThoANQ4YwEEAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"08000130-0000-0000-0000-58dd72da0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1490907866
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far. Do update your question with that information.

Comment: I am new to this document db stuff. Just looking if anyone could direct

Comment: @kishore - there are so many published examples on the web, including in the DocDB repo itself on github, that show things like updating a document.  Please note that StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. Take a look at what's out there, take a stab at it, and edit your question with where you're stuck. I mean, if you already have data in your database, chances are good that you already know how to insert a document, so you're probably not too far from updating.

Comment: Also - the method for updating a document is pretty much the first hit when googling `update property documentdb`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I wanted to update the property value for "Type" and "Workout", such that it doesn't effect other values.

I did a demo for just updating the specified property. The following is my detail steps:

1.Create a C# console project and reference [Azure DocumentDB SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB)

2.Add a TestModel class

```
 public class TestModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // used to set expiration policy
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ttl", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int? TimeToLive { get; set; }
        public string PartyId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
        public int WorkoutId { get; set; }

    }
```

3. Add the document to collection

```
 private static readonly string databaseName = "tomtest";
 private static readonly string collectionName = "colltest";
  // Read config
 private static readonly string endpointUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndPointUrl"];
 private static readonly string authorizationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationKey"];

        var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl),authorizationKey);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("**** Create Documents ****");
        Console.WriteLine();
        var document1Definition = new TestModel
        { 
            Id= Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            PartyId = "10114795",
            Type = "heart-rate-zone-target",
            DateStarted = DateTime.Now,
            WorkoutId = 4
        };

        var database = client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database {Id = databaseName}).Result.Resource;
        var collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
            UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseName), new DocumentCollection
            {
               Id = collectionName
            }).Result.Resource;
        //create document
        var createdocument = client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection.SelfLink, document1Definition).Result.Resource;
```

4.Check the result from the Azure portal

[image]

5.Query the created document

```
 //query document
 var querydoc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TestModel>(
 UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName))
            .Where(x => x.PartyId == "10114795")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .First();
```

6.Update the document.

```
//update document
querydoc.Type = "updateType";
querydoc.WorkoutId = 0;
var result = client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, querydoc.Id), querydoc).Result.Resource;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine($"Update document Type :{ result.GetPropertyValue<string>("Type")} , WorkoutId:{result.GetPropertyValue<int>("WorkoutId")}");
```

7.Check from Azure portal and console.

[image]

[image]

Packages.config

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.13.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Comment: this is very detailed and correct way of doing thanks for pointing out like this.

Comment: you could've just said you're reading the whole document, updating the values in memory and overwriting the whole document.  Partial updates aren't supported, see @GorvGoyl answer

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, partial update is not yet implemented. You can track the process at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document

So, as Tom Sun mentioned you can first retrieve the required document from Cosmos DB, update the properties and replace with the older one.

```
//Fetch the Document to be updated
Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionLink)
                            .Where(r => r.Id == "doc id")    
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .SingleOrDefault();

//Update some properties on the found resource
doc.SetPropertyValue("MyProperty", "updated value");

//Now persist these changes to the database by replacing the original resource
Document updated = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do [Partial document update in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update) in `C#` for your `WorkoutModel` this way:

```
public class WorkoutModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; } = "0c44d1ee-58b8-4083-a702-f770ba0e63e9";
    public int PartyId { get; set; } = 10114795;
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; } = 4;
    public string Type { get; set; } = "heart-rate-zone-target";
    public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; } = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-05T18:14:15.1620890Z");
}


public async Task<WorkoutModel> PartialUpdate(WorkoutModel model, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container = ...;

    string newType = $"CHANGED-{model.Type}";
    int newWorkoutId = model.WorkoutId + 10;

    ItemResponse<WorkoutModel> response = await container.PatchItemAsync<WorkoutModel>(
        id: model.Id,
        // assuming your container uses 'id' field as ID and partition key 
        partitionKey: new PartitionKey(model.Id), 
        patchOperations: new[]
        {
            // 'Add' adds or replaces value depending on if it exists
            PatchOperation.Add("/Type", newType),
            PatchOperation.Add("/WorkoutId", newWorkoutId)
        }, cancellationToken: token);

    return response.Resource;
}
```

After `PartialUpdate` call data will be like that (notice `WorkoutId` and `Type` changes):

```
"PartyId": 10114795,
"WorkoutId": 14,
"Type": "CHANGED-heart-rate-zone-target",
"DateStarted": "2016-02-05T18:14:15.1620890Z",
"id": "0c44d1ee-58b8-4083-a702-f770ba0e63e9",
"_rid": "0ThoANQ4YwEEAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/0ThoAA==/colls/0ThoANQ4YwE=/docs/0ThoANQ4YwEEAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"08000130-0000-0000-0000-58dd72da0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1490907866
```