# Azure Cosmos DB - Update existing documents with an additional field

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Existing Cosmos DB documents need to be altered/updated with a new property & also existing documents of other collections need to be updated with the same new property along with its value.

Is there any recommended way or tool available to update existing documents on Cosmos DB, or is writing the custom c# application/PowerShell script using Cosmos DB SDK is the only option?

Example:

Existing `user` document

```json
{
   id:user1@mail.com,
   name: "abc",
   country: "xyz"
}
```

Updated `user` document

```json
{
   id:user1@mail.com,
   name: "abc",
   country: "xyz",
   guid:"4334fdfsfewr"  //new field
}
```

Existing `order` document of the `user`

```json
{
   id:user1@mail.com,
   user: "user1@mail.com",
   date: "09/28/2020",
   amt: "$45"
}
```

Updated `order` document of the `user`

```json
{
   id:user1@mail.com,
   user: "user1@mail.com",
   userid: "4334fdfsfewr",  // new field but with same value as in user model
   date: "09/28/2020",
   amt: "$45"
}
```

Comment: There is no specific tool for this, as you have specific data you need to add to each document. Seems like you'd need to write code to do this (and each of the supported language SDKs support replacing a document with an updated document). There are also various Azure services, such as Azure Data Factory, but... you'd still need to inject specific data, and you'd need to know how to modify your document. How you choose to do this is really up to you - there's no specific way.

Comment: May be reiterating my requirement will be helpful, I want to update all existing documents in a collection with a NEW property "Guid" and these change also has to be propagated to other specific existing models in the same cosmos db account. Wondering how Azure Data Factory will be used for this requirement? I agree to @deezg suggestion of using Azure functions with Cosmosdb trigger. But still looking for options too.

Comment: Does something this common really have no built-in support...?

Comment: You can do [Partial document update in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update) in C#  [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76425791/804385)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go with:

1. Update user documents through a script
2. Have Azure Function with Cosmosdb trigger that would listen to changes on users documents and update orders appropriately

[UPDATE]
whatever type of script you feel best with: PS, C#, Azure Functions...
now, what do you mean they need to be altered with the new property "on the same time"? i'm not sure that's possible in any way. if you want such an effect then i guess your best bet is:

1. create new collection/container for users
2. have an Azure Function that listens to a change feed for your existing users container (so, with *StartFromBeginning* option)
3. update your documents to have new field and store them in a newly created container
4. once done, switch your application to use new container

its your choice how would you change other collections (orders): using changeFeed & Azure Functions from old or new users container.

PS.
Yes, whatever flow i'd go with, it would still be Azure Functions with Cosmos DB trigger.

Comment: Update user documents through a script, do you mean PS script? Existing cosmos db account has around 100,000 user documents &  'n' number of order documents, is still Azure Function with Cosmosdb trigger holds good? provided all 100,000 user documents have to be altered with new property on same time.

Comment: I don't understand how Azure Functions + Cosmos DB trigger can be decided on, based on the OPs general question. There's really no specific way to accomplish this task.

Comment: @DavidMakogon maybe i'm missing something but he is inserting a guid into users documents. what prevents him from generating that guid and inserting it within azure function?

Comment: @deezg - I wasn't saying they couldn't use an Azure Function. But your answer states that it should *be* an Azure Function. I'm saying there's no definitive way to say that.

Comment: @DavidMakogon i'm pretty sure i never mentioned anything like "should be". I've actually started my post with "i'd probably go with". so, i've proposed one solution which is pretty common for tasks like this and rather often recommended by cosmos db team for similar tasks. not sure what are you trying to say actually. man didn't ask for single, deterministic, definitive way. he asked for recommendation. and i'm pretty sure 9 out of 10 cosmos db people would recommend azure functions + cosmos db trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some solution for .Net Core API 3.0 or higher version.

```
 // You can put any filter for result
            var result = _containers.GetItemLinqQueryable<MessageNoteModel>().Where(d => d.id == Id
                                       && d.work_id.ToLower() == workId.ToLower()).ToFeedIterator();

            if (result.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var existingDocuments = result.ReadNextAsync().Result?.ToList();

                existingDocuments.ForEach(document =>
                {
                    //Creating the partition key of the document
                    var partitionKey = new PartitionKey(document?.work_id);
                    document.IsConversation = true;

                    //Inserting/Updating the message in to cosmos db collection: Name
                    _containers.Twistle.ReplaceItemAsync(document, document.document_id, partitionKey);
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue of updating the Cosmos DB schema for existing documents. We were able to achieve this through a custom JsonSerializer.

We created `CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer` inspired from [Cosmos DB SDK](https://ankitvijay.net/2021/07/18/update-schema-cosmos-db/). `CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer` exposes the `FromStream` method that allows us to deal with raw JSON. You can update the `FromStream` method to update document schema to your latest version. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
 public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
 {
    using (stream)
    {
      if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
      {
          return (T)(object)stream;
      }

      using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
      {
          using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
          {
              var jsonSerializer = GetSerializer();
              return UpdateSchemaVersion<T>(jsonSerializer.Deserialize<JObject>(jsonTextReader));
          }
      }
   }
}

private T UpdateSchemaVersonToCurrent<T>(JObject jObject)
{ 
   // Add logic to update JOjbect to the latest version. For e.g.
   jObject["guid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   return jObject.ToObject<T>();
}
```

You can set `Serializer` to `CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer` in `CosmosClientOptions` while creating `CosmosClient`.

```
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient("<cosmosDBConnectionString>",
            new CosmosClientOptions
            {
                Serializer = new CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer()
            };
```

This way, you always deal with the latest Cosmos document throughout the code, and when you save the entity back to Cosmos, it is persisted with the latest schema version.

You can take this further by running schema migration as a separate process, for example, inside an Azure function, where you load old documents, convert them to the latest version and then save it back to Cosmos.

I also wrote a [post](https://ankitvijay.net/2021/07/18/update-schema-cosmos-db/) on Cosmos document schema update that explains this in detail.